# error running npm and node commands in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio-code

I can execute node commands in a command window like ng serve -o
[image]

But when I try it in VS Code I get this error

ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check if you spelled the name correctly or if
you included a path, check that the path is correct and try again.

I'd started my laptop with the administrator account

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: is `angular cli` globally installed? also try running from `command-prompt` or `git-bash` terminal in vs-code rather than `powershell`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the execution policy

Executing this script is solved

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned